# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add'

Tags: python, set, attributeerror

I got the following error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add'
```

while I tried this.

```
not_yet_bought_set = set()
.
.
.
for value in set_dict.itervalues():
    for item in value:
        not_yet_bought_set = not_yet_bought_set.add(item)
```

I dont't get why I got this error, is it because I always make  not_yet_bought_set new? I make this, because when I only do

```
not_yet_bought_set.add(item)
```

there wont be all the items from all values. I do not know why.

value are sets and

```
not_yet_bought_set.union(value)
```

also generate this error

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
not_yet_bought_set.add(item)
```

this will return `None` and you are assigning it to `not_yet_bought_set`. So, `not_yet_bought_set` becomes `None` now. The next time

```
not_yet_bought_set = not_yet_bought_set.add(item)
```

is executed, `add` will be invoked on `None`. Thats why it fails.

To fix this, simply do this. Dont assign this to anything.

```
 not_yet_bought_set.add(item)
```

Answer (score 3):

[`set.add`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#set.add) returns nothing.

```
>>> s = set()
>>> the_return_value_of_the_add = s.add(1)
>>> the_return_value_of_the_add is None
True
```

Replace following line:

```
not_yet_bought_set = not_yet_bought_set.add(item)
```

with:

```
not_yet_bought_set.add(item)
```